# How to use NotifierHandler with monolog in Symfony 5.4

Tags: symfony, handler, monolog

i can't use this handler in monolog configuration :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Monolog/Handler/NotifierHandler.php

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    discord:
      type: notifier
      action_level: error
```

this is the error message : There is no handler class defined for handler "notifier".

How can i inject this handler ?

BR, Thomas

Comment: Please don't add answers inside the question. If you find a solution, you can Answer your own question adding it in "Your Answer" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the notifier handler to `services.yaml`

See: https://manyou.blog/send-symfony-logs-to-slack-with-symfony-notifier-as-a-monolog-handler#heading-add-notifierhandler-as-service